# Foreach + ajax = invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-extensions

есть массив, перебираю его с помощью ForEach. В теории всё должно быть просто, делаем запрос к гугл расширению, если его нет, тогда должно выводится ``"error: " + i```, если оно есть, то соответственно: `"success: " + i`

Но всегда выводится ошибка, хотя у меня установлено расширение, которое есть в массиве.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно заметить, что на самом деле скрипт обращается не к тем ссылкам, которые формируются, а всегда к:

**chrome-extension://invalid/**

Вот код, который не работает

```
let ex = [
    "cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm",
    "cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb",
    "mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij",
    "ohahllgiabjaoigichmmfljhkcfikeof",
    "gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom",
    "lgblnfidahcdcjddiepkckcfdhpknnjh",
    "lalfpjdbhpmnhfofkckdpkljeilmogfl",
    "elhcnbjoomhmifmfeggoalmplblcmcin",
    "naffoicfphgmlgikpcmghdooejkboifd",
    "hnmpcagpplmpfojmgmnngilcnanddlhb",
    "edbgmecmoefpnbkhgenlpijpjpnapenm",
    "ddihdkhaegjhogakhoccdehabbjlaoff"
];

ex.forEach(function(item, i) {

    let urrl = 'chrome-extension://' + item + '/manifest.json';

    $.ajax({
        url: urrl,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function(){
            console.log("error: " + i);
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log("success: " + i);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт обращается к корректным ссылкам, это можно увидеть, добавив в функцию ошибки:

```
console.log(urrl);
```

сообщение //invalid говорит о том, что вы не можете обратиться к такому расширению методом HEAD (его нет в хроме или хром блокирует обращение к нему).
У меня по моему расширению хром ругнулся вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но ведь зайти на него я могу, просто перейдя по ссылке, почему скрипту нельзя? И можно ли это как-то обойти?

Comment: Судя по всему, если в файлах манифест этих расширений не прописан url страницы, с которой вы туда хотите обратиться, хром будет блокировать такие запросы. Это политика безопасности.
Больше скажу - при помощи xmlhttprequest(), при помощи .load() и даже используя iframe ответ хрома всегда такой - он не дает скриптам обратиться к файлам расширений без прописания вашего url как доверенного в манифесте расширения.